# How to bind a slider value to nested collections?

Tags: wpf, collections, binding, slider

I am trying to create a utility that will display general utilization stats for each node in a server farm. Not only will this give me a general snapshot at any point in time, but will let me see how the impact on 1 node affects another.

The data is an observable collection of nodes.
Each node has four series which are observable collections of doubles that represent the % utilization of each server resource (CPU, Disk, Memory, Network).

```
    <DockPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Nodes}}">
        <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Series}" />
        <Slider DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="Black" Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding Path=[0].CPU.Count}" ></Slider>
    </DockPanel>
```

Each Item in the ListBox is a server node. What I'm binding to in the DataTemplate is a Grid with 4 sections for each series, and a textbox with the current value in the series.

(Data Template Snippet)

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
<TextBox Text="{Binding CPU[0]}" />
```

I want to change the slider to update all the nodes' series' current item.

Its the "[0]" part that I'm having trouble with, I want the indexer to be tied to the Slider value, its like I want a binding within a binding. Is it possible to do something like `Text="{Binding CPU[{Binding Path=Slider.Value}]}"`?

Comment: WPF was designed to support the pattern MVVM closely. So many problems (like this one) will be solved by just changing the MVVM appropriately. In this case you need some property namely `Index` in your ViewModel, bind that `Index` to some Slider value. Also you need to add any property depending on that index, such as you may need to add some property namely `CurrentCPU`, this will be evalulated from `CPU` and the current `Index` (in code behind). So instead of binding to `CPU[index]`, you just need to bind to `CurrentCPU`. That's how it should be done.